# geolocation stopped working on insecure locations hence on ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

Using geolocation (Cordova Plugin or javascript) with ionic to get user locations until it recently stopped working, console logging the following error:

`getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See ... for more details.`

[image]

Following is the code

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
        var data = {
            Lati: pos.coords.latitude,
            Longi: pos.coords.longitude,
            /*LoginID: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('LoginId'))*/
            EmpCode: localStorage.getItem('LoginId')
        };
        console.log(pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude);
        $http.post("https://someapi", data).success(function (rsdata, status) {

            console.log(data.Lati + "," + data.Longi);
        })

    }, function (error) {
        alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });}
```

Comment: That's a more global issue: https://mobiforge.com/news-comment/no-https-then-bye-bye-geolocation-in-chrome-50 ...Web is going to be a secure place and that's means: everything **https**

Comment: @Hitmands I know it is deprecated..but cannot find a way out to get it work with ionic as i can make a website https:// but not an application

Comment: I think there's anything at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add a a valid certificate to your server and serve the everything via https. Or for testing purposes follow the suggestions here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Comment: apis are already on a secure server (https://) 
we cannot put ionic code on a server as it bundles with the apk

Comment: I'm confused - are you building an app or a web page? In an app, if you use the Geolocation plugin, it will just plain work.

Comment: The screenshot in the initial post shows a browser window therefore I assumed that the error occurs in the web app, not inside the apk

Answer (score 0):

**This code past in for loading 1st page.**

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        localStorage.setItem('masterLati', pos.coords.latitude);
        localStorage.setItem('masterLong', pos.coords.longitude);
      }, function(error) {
        alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
      });
```

**And Post Your Lat Long on server.**

```
$scope.postOnClickButton = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner>'
    });

    var masterLati = localStorage.getItem('masterLati');
    var masterLong = localStorage.getItem('masterLong');

    var getLogUserId = document.getElementById('userLogInId').value;
    var getLogUserPswd = document.getElementById('userpswdId').value;
    var dataString = 'email=' + getLogUserId + '&password=' + getLogUserPswd + '&lati=' + masterLati + '&long=' + masterLong;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '' + globURL + 'login.php',
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
         $ionicLoading.hide();

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm Doing the same thing directly calling the api to store the coordinates..
issue being i'm unable to get the coordinates as geolocation() considers the script running on an insecure source

Comment: ok then remove remove your old one plugin and install this one                        "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation"

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps/issues/15) which basically means this feature will not be supported in the future and applicable only for HTTPs sites. Also looks like there are no plans to create an equivalent replacement for HTTP use.